# Quadratic Order of BCH Expansion

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus

I am looking for a closed-form of the second-order term in the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff (BCH) expansion of $\log{e^X e^Y}$. Specifically, in this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases) article, one has

$$ \log{e^X e^Y} = X + \frac{\mathrm{ad}_X}{I - e^{-\mathrm{ad}_X}} Y + O (Y^2) . \tag{1} $$

I would like to know the explicit form of the operator $U(X)$ that would go with the $O(Y^2)$-term in (1). For example, something like

$$ \log{e^X e^Y} = X + \frac{\mathrm{ad}_X}{I - e^{-\mathrm{ad}_X}} Y + Y U(X) Y + O(Y^3) , \tag{2} $$

or similar.

**Remarks.** I understand that the linear term $\frac{\mathrm{ad}_X}{I - e^{-\mathrm{ad}_X}}$ in (1) follows from the integral formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_integral_formula) via first-order Taylor expansion with respect to $Y$ about $Y = 0$. Hence, the second-order term I seek sould follow from retaining the quadratic order in the Taylor expansion.